# Global variable structure (DB) in JSP-project

Tags: jsp, servlets

For my educational JSP-project (Servlets, Java EE) I have to implement the database in Java. In the index page, I also execute function to build the database (not MySQL, but something like `HashMap` based structure with links to objects) and fill it with basic data. My issue is that I can't make this «database» global and can't access to this structure from every page of the site.

How can I pass pointer/link to this structure to all JSP-site page?

Comment: Why can't you make it global? Why do you have to implement it like this?

Comment: This is not small temp project, that was started not by me and all what I need is to fix this stuff, that users can't access to global HashMap and perform query from any page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it as a servlet context attribute on webapp's startup. You could use a `ServletContextListener` for this.

```
@WebListener
public class DatabaseConfigurator implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Map<String, Object> database = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("database", database);
    }

    // ...
}
```

It's available in all servlets as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> database = (Map<String, Object>) getServletContext().getAttribute("database");
// ...
```

It's availablew in all JSPs as follows:

```
${database}
```

*(the map value is available by the map key by the usual EL means as in `${map.key}`)*

Answer (score 1):

Write a `servlet`, populate result from the database (prepare a List), bind that result to request's attribute (or session attribute) and forward it to JSP via `RequestDispatcher`. In JSP you can iterate that list using `EL` and `JSTL`.